# How to keep score in a python Rock,Paper,Scissors game

Tags: python

I am writing a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors in Python. The game will continue looping until the player opts to quit. When the player decides to finally quit, I want to have the program print the player and computer score. I have the following code, but the score counter I wrote in does not seem to be working. It only displays a 1 and the other two are 0's. Can someone explain why this is happening and how I can resolve it?

```
ValidPlays = ['r','p','s','q']
while PlayerChoice.lower() not in ValidPlays:
    print(PlayerChoice,'is not a valid play. Please enter a valid choice.')
    PlayerChoice = input('Your move: ')
while PlayerChoice != 'q':      
    from random import randint
    ComputerChoice = randint(1,3)
    CompMove = ''
    if ComputerChoice == 1:
        CompMove = 'r'
    elif ComputerChoice ==2:
        CompMove = 'p'
    else:
        CompMove = 's'
    print("Computer's move:",CompMove)

    RockWinMsg = 'Rock smashes Scissors!'
    PaperWinMsg = 'Paper covers Rock!'
    ScissorsWinMsg = 'Scissors cut Paper!'

    PlayerScore = 0
    CompScore = 0
    TieScore = 0

    if PlayerChoice.lower() == 'r' and CompMove == 'r':
        print('Tie!')
        TieScore = TieScore +1
    elif PlayerChoice.lower() == 'r' and CompMove == 'p':
        print(PaperWinMsg)
        print('Computer wins!')
        CompScore = CompScore +1
    elif PlayerChoice.lower() == 'r' and CompMove == 's':
        print(RockWinMsg)
        print(PlayerName,'wins!')
        PlayerScore = PlayerScore +1
        PlayerScore = PlayerScore +1
    if PlayerChoice.lower() == 'p' and CompMove == 'r':
        print(PaperWinMsg)
        print(PlayerName,'wins!')
    elif PlayerChoice.lower() == 'p' and CompMove == 'p':
        print('Tie!')
        TieScore = TieScore +1
    elif PlayerChoice.lower() == 'p' and CompMove == 's':
        print(ScissorsWinMsg)
        print('Computer wins!')
        CompScore = CompScore +1
    if PlayerChoice.lower() == 's' and CompMove == 'r':
        print(RockWinMsg)
        print('Computer wins!')
        CompScore = CompScore +1
    elif PlayerChoice.lower() == 's' and CompMove == 'p':
        print(ScissorsWinMsg)
        print(PlayerName,'wins!')
        PlayerScore = PlayerScore +1
    elif PlayerChoice.lower() == 's' and CompMove == 's':
        print('Tie!')
        TieScore = TieScore +1


    PlayerChoice = input('If you would like to play again, enter your move, otherwise enter q quit: ')

print('Player Score:',PlayerScore)
print('Computer Score:',CompScore)
print('Ties:',TieScore)
```

Comment: You are setting all the scores to 0 inside the loop, so each round they get reset.

Comment: Oh wow, that was easy. Thanks a lot!